# Why is the `await` keyword often omitted when using the shared_preferences plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, dart-async, flutter-sharedpreference

While using shared prefs plugin it's common to explore code like below

```
void saveList() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setStringList("listKey", aList); //await isn't used
}
```

where `setStringList` returns a `Future<bool>` so that why in this case the `await` isn't used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` isn't used in your example because it wouldn't do anything and therefore would be unnecessary.

The purpose of `await` is to make subsequent code wait for the `Future` to complete.  That is, if you have:

```dart
await foo();
bar();
```

then your program would wait for `foo()` to asynchronously complete before invoking `bar()`.

If you have:

```dart
Future<void> baz() async {
  await foo();
}
```

that's implicitly equivalent to:

```dart
Future<void> baz() async {
  await foo();
  return;
}
```

and your program would wait for `foo()` to asynchronously complete before "returning" from `baz()`. ("Returning" from an asynchronous function actually means completing the returned `Future`.)

In your example:

> ```dart
> void saveList() async {
>   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
>   prefs.setStringList("listKey", aList);
> }
> ```

There is nothing left to do after `prefs.setStringList` completes.  There is no code afterward that depends on its completion, neither in `saveList` itself nor in `saveList`'s callers. (Since `saveList` returns `void` instead of a `Future`, it is a "fire-and-forget" function; callers cannot wait for it to complete even if they wanted to.) Therefore, using `await prefs.setStringList(...)` wouldn't change any behavior and wouldn't serve any purpose.

Comment: What if the list is somehow weights and I do something like (in button): 
`onPressed() async { await saveList(); setState(); }` where in rebuild some saved data should be used. Is it possible that in `build()` those data could be requested before the data will be saved in `saveList` ?

Comment: @rozerro `await saveList()` is wrong.  As I already explained, `saveList()` does not return a `Future`.

Comment: yea, I meant if the `saveList()` would have a signature `Future<void>` (it's still a legal signature for the `saveList()` func)

Comment: @rozerro If `saveList` did return a `Future<void>`, then it would need `await prefs.setStringList(...)`.  Without that, `saveList` would signal completion before the preferences would finish being saved.